# python: unpacking an array of dictionaries in a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I am relatively new to python, and a piece of existing code has created an object akin to per below. This is part of a legacy piece of code. i can unfortunately not change it. The code creates many objects that look like the following format:

```
[[{'a': 2,'b': 3}],[{'a': 1,'c': 3}],[{'c': 2,'d': 4}]]
```

I am trying to create transform this object into a matrix or numpy arrays. In this specific example - it would have three rows (1,2,3) and 4 columns (a,b,c,d), with the dictionary values inserted in the cells. (I have inserted how this matrix would look as a dinky toy example. However - i am not looking to recreate the table from scratch, but i am looking for code that translate the object per above in a matrix format).

I am struggling to find a fast and easy way to do this. Any tips or advice much appreciated.

```
   a  b  c  d
1  2  3  0  0
2  1  0  3  0
3  0  2  0  4
```

Comment: Add in the expected output?

Comment: There is no such thing as `a[3]`.  Even the sub-list has only three elements, and `a` has only one.

Comment: Completely unclear what you're asking. Provide the output you want for your list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are focusing on the fast and easy, when you need to address the how first.  This isn't the normal input format for `np.array` or `pandas.  So let's focus on that.

It's a list of lists; suggesting a 2d array.  But each sublist contains one dictionary, not a list of values.

```
In [633]: dd=[[{'a': 2,'b': 3}],[{'a': 1,'c': 3}],[{'c': 2,'d': 4}]]
In [634]: dd[0]
Out[634]: [{'b': 3, 'a': 2}]
```

So let's define a function that converts a dictionary into a list of numbers.  We can address the question of where `a,b,c,d` labels come from, and whether you need to collect them from `dd` or not, later.

```
In [635]: dd[0][0]
Out[635]: {'b': 3, 'a': 2}
In [636]: def mk_row(adict):
    return [adict.get(k,0) for k in ['a','b','c','d']]
   .....: 
In [637]: mk_row(dd[0][0])
Out[637]: [2, 3, 0, 0]
```

So now we just need to apply the function to each sublist

```
In [638]: [mk_row(d[0]) for d in dd]
Out[638]: [[2, 3, 0, 0], [1, 0, 3, 0], [0, 0, 2, 4]]
```

This is the kind of list that @Colin fed to `pandas`.  It can also be given to `np.array`:

```
In [639]: np.array([mk_row(d[0]) for d in dd])
Out[639]: 
array([[2, 3, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 4]])
```

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj - for taking the time to work on this. I think that the solution per below might work as well - just stumbled upon this dd=[[{'a': 2,'b': 3}],[{'a': 1,'c': 3}],[{'c': 2,'d': 4}]]
a = [b[0] for b in dd]
c = pandas.DataFrame(a)
c.fillna(0)

Comment: I don't use `pandas` enough to know the variety of inputs that it accepts.  But a list of dictionaries makes sense, given its purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Simpy use:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('1', [2, 3, 0,0]), ('2', [1, 0, 3,0]),('3', [0, 2, 0,4])], orient='index', columns=['a', 'b', 'c','d'])


arr = df.values
```

You can then reference it like a normal `numpy` array:

```
print(arr[0,:])
```